# NLTK Brill demo does not produce errors.out

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm reading the book *Natural Language Processing with Python* recently. At Section 5.6 *Transformation-Based Tagging*, the code `print(open("errors.out").read())`doesn't work and gives the following error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Practice/NLP/Chapter5.py", line 337, in <module>
    print(open("errors.out").read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'errors.out'
```

The whole code from this demo is

```
from nltk.tbl import demo as brill_demo
brill_demo.demo()
print(open("errors.out").read())
```

When I delete the last code line `print(open("errors.out").read())`, it works well and can output results.

Maybe the code line is suitable for python 2.x, but I'm using python 3.7 and haven't found an effective solution yet. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I can confirm that the instructions at https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html#transformation-based-tagging do not match what I see when I download NLTK and run the demo. Examining the code, I see a method `demo_error_analysis()` which should produce _vaguely_ a file like this, but with a different name. Probably a bug in the book ...?  Maybe related to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/549

Comment: @tripleee Thanks a lot! I've solved the problem. I think the reason is exactly what you said. The method ```demo_error_analysis()``` can create a file named *errors.txt*. Then we can use ```print(open("errors.txt").read())``` to see the content~ To succeffully create the file, we also need to change the source file *nltk/tbl/demo.py*. Find ```u"\n".join(error_list(gold_data, taggedtest)).encode("utf-8") + "\n"```  and delete ```.encode("utf-8")``` Then we can get *errors.txt*!